# Write array formatted to file

Tags: php

I want to write this array

```
$array = [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => [
        'subkey1' => 'value3'
     ],
     'key3' => 'value4'
];
```

to the config, which should look like:

config.php

```
<?php
return [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => [
        'subkey1' => 'value3'
     ],
     'key3' => 'value4'
];
?>
```

With this format I can later include the file like this:

index.php

```
$config = include 'config.php';
```

Is that possible with a common PHP function? I know, thats not possible with var_export and print_r.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Can you please give us a clarity about what's your requirement...

Comment: _Is that possible with a common PHP function?_ no, not with the shorthand version, possible with `var_export` though

Comment: This is where I prefer to use `serialize`. I can make a file by printing `'$var = unzerialize("'.serialize($my_variable).'");';` Then, I can encode any variable type I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create the variable in config.php then it is loaded when you include the file in index.php like this:

config.php

```
<?php
$config = [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => [
        'subkey1' => 'value3'
     ],
     'key3' => 'value4'
];
?>
```

index.php

```
include "config.php";
$value4 = $config['key3']; // 'value4'
```

made some assumptions because your question had very little information, hopefully this helps!